# How to Reassign an Advanced Approvals request via Apex

Tags: cpq, cpq-api, advanced-approvals

I have a business requirement that when a record is submitted for approval with Advanced Approvals, to evaluate a set of criteria, and if it the criteria is satisfied, immediately reassign the approval.

I am aware of two Advanced Approvals APIs:

1. [Advanced Approvals API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_aa_intro.htm) provides a way to approve or reject an approval request via an ApexRest service.
2. The class `SBAA.ApprovalAPI` exposes 4 methods (`submit`, `recall`, `preview`, `processRecords`), which allow approval requests to be submitted or recalled.  I can't find full documentation of this API, but I have found it referenced in [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_enable_aa.htm&type=5) and [Knowledge](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385508&type=1).

I have not found an API for reassigning approval requests.  In the UI, there is a button on the Approval object to reassign, so I'm hopeful that there is an API as well.  It may be possible to simply edit the Approval record via code, but I've not found that documented as approved, and seems likely to run amiss of unpublished expectations of the AA managed package.